# ContourPlot or DensityPlot ColorFunction with x, y and z arguments

Tags: plotting, color

Is it possible to apply a color function to `ContourPlot` or `DensityPlot` that is function of `x`, `y` and `z`, and not simply of `z`?

Example:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[#1 > 1/2, Red, White] &)]
```

but colored only for  `x > 2 Pi` (obviously, there are alternative methods for this example, but typical cases are more complex)

Comment: Not if the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html) are correct.  `ContourPlot` appears to pass only a single value.  You could try to generate the contours and the background colour separately, then combine them together to achieve the effect.

Comment: @Szabolcs on this case it is easy, for others, only by doing a ContourPlot that outputs the color value on z, and then use it as backbroud, which is clearly a non optimum solution.

Comment: This is not going to be of as good a quality as ContourPlot, and it's again just a hack: `DensityPlot[(x - 2 Pi) Sign[Cos[x] + Cos[y]], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 
  4 Pi}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, Cos[x] + Cos[y]]}, 
 Mesh -> 5, PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones", 
 Exclusions -> None]`

Comment: The colouring and the contours are treated separately by specifying one as "the function to plot" and the other as "mesh functions".  Instead of using mesh function, you could generate the contour lines with ContourPlot for better quality, then combine with Show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `ColorFunction` receives only one parameter, the value of the function, when called by `ContourPlot`. This is explained in the details of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html). A crude way to see that would be printing the argument received by `ColorFunction` :

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}
 , ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Print[{x, y, z}]; If[x > 1/2, Red, White]]]
```

So I guess the answer is no, if you want to use `ColorFunction` on `ContourPlot`.

Another solution could be to superimpose your `ContourPlot` into a `RegionPlot` or another graphic function that would provide `{x,y}` to the `ColorFunction`:

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[
  Cos[x] + Cos[y] > 0 && 2 x > y, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]]],
 ContourPlot[
  Cos[x] + Cos[y] == Range[-2, 2, 0.25], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any other solutions? It is so strange that `ContourPlot` can use `ColorFunction` with `z` argument only.